# using GPIO Reading from 4 inputs give me non accurate output

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I am trying to read from 4 inputs to get an integer value but when I test my code the actual value does not match the expected

**My Code:**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os, time
i=0
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
a = [0,0,0,0,0]
while True:
 n1=GPIO.input(22)
 n2=GPIO.input(23)
 n3=GPIO.input(4)
 n4=GPIO.input(17)
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==0):
   if(n3==0):
    if(n4==0):#0000
     a[i]=0
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==0):
   if(n3==0):
    if(n4==1):#0001
     a[i]=1
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==0):
   if(n3==1):
    if(n4==0):#0010
     a[i]=2
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==0):
   if(n3==1):
    if(n4==1):#0011
     a[i]=3
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==1):
   if(n3==0):
    if(n4==0):#0100
     a[i]=4
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==1):
   if(n3==0):
    if(n4==0):#0101
     a[i]=5    
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==1):
   if(n3==1):
    if(n4==0):#0110
     a[i]=6
 if(n1==0):
  if(n2==1):
   if(n3==1):
    if(n4==1):#0111
     a[i]=7
 i=i+1
 print a
 if(i==5):
  break
```

Output is always a=[0,0,0,0,0] so, I want to know what is the problem in my code?

Comment: We are rather stymied as you haven't bothered to tell us the input values, what results you expect, and the actual results.  You could replace all the ifs with one statement: a[i] = (n1<<3) | (n2<<2) | (n3 << 1) | (n4 <<0).

Comment: @joan in all cases lets say 5 4 3 2 1 (each number in binary format)

a output is [0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: I would highly suggest refactoring that.  There are so many ways in which that could more easily be written.  For example, why are you repeating `if n1==0: ` over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code (apart from the test for #0101 is wrong).

I've converted it to pigpio as it's much easier to test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

i=0

a = [0,0,0,0,0]

pi = pigpio.pi()

while True:
   n1=pi.read(22)
   n2=pi.read(23)
   n3=pi.read(4)
   n4=pi.read(17)

   a[i] = (n1<<3) | (n2<<2) | (n3 << 1) | (n4 <<0)
   i=i+1
   print i,a
   if(i==5):
      break

pi.stop()
```

.

```
$ pigs w 22 0 w 23 0 w 4 0 w 17 0
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [0L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [0L, 0L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [0L, 0L, 0L, 0, 0]
4 [0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0]
5 [0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L]
$ pigs w 22 0 w 23 0 w 4 0 w 17 1
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [1L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [1L, 1L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [1L, 1L, 1L, 0, 0]
4 [1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0]
5 [1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L]
$ pigs w 22 0 w 23 1 w 4 0 w 17 1
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [5L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [5L, 5L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [5L, 5L, 5L, 0, 0]
4 [5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0]
5 [5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L]
$ pigs w 22 1 w 23 1 w 4 0 w 17 1
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [13L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [13L, 13L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [13L, 13L, 13L, 0, 0]
4 [13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 0]
5 [13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L]
$ pigs w 22 1 w 23 1 w 4 1 w 17 1
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [15L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [15L, 15L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [15L, 15L, 15L, 0, 0]
4 [15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 0]
5 [15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L]
$ pigs w 22 1 w 23 0 w 4 0 w 17 1
$ /code/forum/MarcFoi_2.py  
1 [9L, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [9L, 9L, 0, 0, 0]
3 [9L, 9L, 9L, 0, 0]
4 [9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 0]
5 [9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L]
$
```

Comment: Thanks @joan , now part of the problem has been solved (always output [0,0,0,0,0])
but there is a problem it should take new input in each loop so the array value should be different for different input,why it does not take different input in each loop .

Comment: It takes the input available at the start of the loop.  I'd have to type very fast to enter new values faster than a Python loop.  As a test you could start PWM on the gpios to vary the values rapidly, e.g. pigs p 22 128 p 23 150 p 4 170 p 17 20.  What facility have you got to change the gpio values rapidly?

Comment: i take the actual values from another device so i can't insure that all values would change faster than the python loop, how to make the loop wait for the changes ?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you are trying to achieve.  The question is now unrelated to your original question.

Comment: sorry if I could not clarify my goal. 

I want to achieve that when my script to work correctly with the actual RP as when i test it on my RP it print out [0,0,0,0,0]

My script as above is reading 4 inputs from from 4 pins 5 times 
to create at the end array look like that [2,3,2,1,2] each element of the array is calculated in one loop.

Comment: I'm going to assume you only want to record a new entry on a gpio change.  So have variables last_n1, to last_n4 initialised to -1.  After reading the inputs don't do anything (apart from a short sleep) if none of n1..n4 are different to the corresponding last_n1..last_n4.  When one has changed add it to your array and set last_n1..last_n4 from n1..n4.

Comment: @joan Just a little curious about your setup and how you tested this particular problem. What is pigs ? Simulator or something ?

Comment: @dastaan [pigs](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) is a command line utility which talks to the pigpio daemon by its socket interface (pigs is part of the pigpio archive).  The Python module talks to the daemon via the socket interface as well. You can do pretty much anything you want to do with the gpios by using pigs from the command line.  Using pigs above would have changed the gpios from inputs to outputs but that is irrelevant to the script being tested, as when you read from a gpio set as an output you still read the current level.